# How to produce unformatted output from man?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I stumbled over this problem with the following simplified example:

```
man zsh|grep zshparam
```

produces no output, even though the zsh-manpage contains pretty close to the top the string *zshparam*. Investigating the problem with

```
man zsh|xxd
```

it occured to me that the man-output is formatted (groff ?), and the string *zshparam* is represented in the man-page output as

```
00000210: 616e 7369 6f6e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 5f08  ansion.       _.
00000220: 7a5f 0873 5f08 685f 0870 5f08 615f 0872  z_.s_.h_.p_.a_.r
00000230: 5f08 615f 086d 2020 2020 205a 7368 2070  _.a_.m     Zsh p
00000240: 6172 616d 6574 6572 730a 2020 2020 2020  arameters.
```

man has dutifully inserted formatting code so that the word *zshparam* is nicely displayed in bold, and of course `grep` can't find it. In the Linux implementation of *man*, this styling is AFIK turned off if the stdout of `man` goes to a pipe, but this is obviously not the case in *BSD*-man.

Is there a way to persuade man **not** to style its output, or is there a utility which can remove this styling information from the generated man-page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196806/did-man-ls-temp-txt-output-textfile-is-corrupted
A lot of good info there. In short you can `man zsh | col -b | grep zshparam`

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek : Thanks for the link. Indeed `col -b` does the job. BTW, the other solution recommended on this page (i.e. `man -t`) did **not** work for my case; the resulting output still seems to contain the raw troff code.

Comment: Instead of fighting `man` why not use `less` 's search feature. Using your example-  `man -P "less -p zshparam" zsh`.